# Multiple writes per seconds appending data to 1 GB file using Ubuntu without performance issues. Possible?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cat

I have an ever growing text file. It will eventually grow to over 1GB or well over.

I am using Ubuntu and a shell script the append/cat the data from multiple small text files to 1 large file sometimes with multiple writes per second.

Currently, and without issue it has grown to over 60MB while writing the data from 113,500 smaller text files to it. All the text files are in the same directory as the file the data is getting written to.

My concerns are how can I improve performance and speed up the read/write process without degrading performance.

Here is the shell script I am using that is batching them 500 at a time and running via cron every 3 minutes.

Thoughts? Ideas? Better Method?

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
d=500

for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -name file1.txt -a ! -name file2.txt  ! -name file3.txt \))
do
    cat $file >> cat.txt
    rm $file
    c=$((c+1))
    if [ $c -eq $d ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Remove `>> cat.txt` and append it to `done` to open and close file `cat.txt` only once in this loop.

Comment: Make sure `cat.txt` is no result of your `find` command.

Comment: `for x in $(...)` is dangerously buggy in and of itself. Very Bad Things happen if you have a file created with `touch '*'` in your results, for example -- you'd find `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` being deleted if they were in your current working directory, for example. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind for guidance on iterating over output from `find` safely and correctly.

Comment: Consider running your code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds. (Each error code is a link to a wiki page describing the problem and how to fix it; those wiki pages are useful).

Answer (score 1):

Possible improvements:

- Just do all the files in one go:

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -name file1.txt -a ! -name file2.txt  ! -name file3.txt \) -exec cat {} >> cat.txt +
  ```

  Doing 500 of them at a time just adds a check which you probably don't care about, and spawns many more `cat` processes than necessary. You'll need to delete the files separately, but you can simply do that by changing the `-exec` part to just `-delete`. If files have to be deleted as they are processed, because new files might be coming in, you can simply write a small script to use instead of `cat` in the command above:

  ```
  cat "$@"
  rm "$@"
  ```
- If you are using harddisks as storage medium, save the output file to a different one from the source files. This reduces the need for searching.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the quick response. Are you saying remove the for loop? Now you have me thinking though what happens if files keep getting added as the process is running?

Comment: We'd want to put both the `-exec` and the `-delete` actions on the same `find` invocation to make sure they occur to the same files.

Comment: That said, if you have files added on an ongoing process, this whole approach is probably the Wrong Thing, and you (@MikeP) should probably be using something like [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) to detect when each file is **finished** being created (as by triggering on the `close` event); otherwise, you can append and delete a file that's only half-written by the software still in the process of creating it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - So with incron it will first check to ensure that another process isn't running prior to executing a new cron process? I am installing now and giving it a go.

Comment: @MikeP, no, it doesn't check that, but one of the triggers you can use is on a close event. So if it triggers an event for that file, you know that the file has been closed by whatever other software was writing it.

Comment: @MikeP, ...checking whether any other software has a handle on a given file is both expensive and race-condition-prone. It can be done -- `fuser` will do it, for instance -- but there's no guarantee that the answer is still accurate when you get it back, and it requires polling.

Comment: @MikeP, ...not that there aren't ways to safely lock files -- `fuser` will do the trick, and there are also idioms around renaming a file to its final name only when fully written -- but they all require the process creating the file to cooperate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried combining `-exec` and `-delete`, and even though the `-delete` was last, `find` actually removed the files before the command had time to process them. Maybe it works with one file at a time (`{} \;`), but that's inefficient for lots of files.

Comment: @l0b0, correct, you need to use the `;` form there -- which also lets `exec` veto the `-delete` by returning a non-successful exit value.